# remove "ال" or "اَلْ" or "الْ" or "اَل" in from first string in arab word

Tags: c#

remove "ال" or "اَلْ" or "الْ" or "اَل" in from first string in arab word

اَلْفَرَقَ will return فَرَقَ

اَلفَرَقَ will return فَرَقَ

الْفَرَقَ will return فَرَقَ

الفَرَقَ will return فَرَقَ

here is what i have tried

```
public static string RemoveAl(string input)
{
if (input.StartsWith("ال"))
return input = input.Substring(2);

if (input.StartsWith("اَلْ"))
return input = input.Substring(4);

if (input.StartsWith("الْ") || input.StartsWith("اَل"))
return input = input.Substring(3);

return input;
}
```

but i think this is not good way is there good way to do that?

Comment: So you only want to remove it if it's in the beginning of the string? There isn't anything "not good" about your approach if that's the case.

Comment: There's an overload of `string.StartsWith` that takes a `CultureInfo` as a parameter. I'm not familiar with Arabic cultures (in the Windows sense) but there may be one that ignores the presence or absence of things like sukun or hamza (or sheddah, etc.) - somewhat like an English "ignore case" flag. It seems pretty reasonable given how written Arabic is pretty loose about when the should show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refactor the code using an array like this:

```
static public string RemoveAl(string input)
{
  string[] prefixes = { "ال", "اَلْ", "الْ", "اَل" };
  foreach (string prefix in prefixes)
    if ( input.StartsWith(prefix) )
    {
      input = input.Substring(prefix.Length);
      break;
    }
  return input;
}
```

Comment: thanks for yout answer how about the performance, is it efficienent ?

Comment: In a second time of refactoring and for speed performance we can move the array as static at the class level to avoid creating it each time (we lost an encapsulation level in case it is used only here), and use a for instead a foreach, and we can use an array of integers to avoid calling length each time. Since it is arabic here it is preferable to use the native StartsWith and Substring. But in fact for speed optimization, you may keep the original question multi if version... It depends of what you call *performance*. For me it is a balanced state between speed and clean code.